# UIPageViewController doesn't release memory when page is flipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on an ebook project, I am using ARC as well, however, when I flip the page in simulator, my memory grows rapidly, by the time I finish flipping it is close to 200MB. It seems memory is not being released, but isn't that what ARC is for? I removed my NSTimer and delegates all together to see if that was the culprit but to no avail. It seems like I have a retain cycle somewhere and I can't seem to find it. I am not using blocks either... Any ideas?

edit: This is a UIPageViewController app

I replaced the following code

```
        - (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard {
            // Return the data view controller for the given index.
            if (([self.pageData count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageData count])) {
                return nil;
            }
            // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
            DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
        with
        - (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard {
            // Return the data view controller for the given index.
            if (([self.pageData count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageData count])) {
                return nil;
            }
            // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
            DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:self.pageData[index]];
```

where self.pageData[index] is the id of a viewcontroller in the storyboard.  I would expect the pageViewController to release this viewController when it asks for the next viewController

Comment: Use the "Instruments" utility to view allocations.  It can show you what objects exist and where they were created.

Comment: A quick note on your comment about ARC... with ARC the compiler will take care of the reference counting for you and do the memory management calls... but if you're (*unintentionally*) holding on to objects, it won't get rid of them ;) I'm guessing that the pages in the `UIPageViewController` are big, and that's the memory build up. Like Phillip said, try investigating with Instruments, or, just review your code. You might spot the mistake... (or post some of it in your question).

Comment: The only difference between the template and my app is each page is a different viewController, instead of reusing the same view controller...
I added the code to my question as well

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research it appears that UIPageViewController intentionally keeps a permanent  reference to all view controllers and never released them (even with ARC)
The solution was to call [self setView:nil] manually when I switch pages.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue where the controller retains pages, and this is a problem. Could you elaborate on "UIPageViewController *intentionally* keeps a permanent reference". Is this behavior documented somewhere? I would assume this is a bug...

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue. Can you elaborate on where and when you call [self setView:nil];?